# skype recieve message not working , getting 403

Tags: botframework, http-status-code-403, azure-bot-service

we used this sample to create a bot to respond to images, but from today, the receive image is not working and is giving 403.

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-ReceiveAttachment

It was working till yesterday. Can somebody help here?

Comment: `the receive image is not working and is giving 403` To detect if something wrong with that Bot app or **MicrosoftAppId**&**MicrosoftAppPassword** cause the issue, you can try to generate and provide a new password for your Bot app, or you can try to create a new Bot app and deploy the code sample to that new Bot app to check if it works as expected.

Comment: The text send and receive is working with the credentials provided. It is the image receive which has issue.

Comment: Provided sample url doesn't work anymore - couold you provide inline sample?

Comment: That sample is using Microsoft.Bot.Builder v3.8 ... have you tried upgrading it to the latest version?